# "insuffiecient allowance" running my unit test

Tags: truffle-test, unittesting, erc-20-approve, transferfrom, allowance

I'm developing in remix a lottery SC. I have a problem when I run buyTicket() function. On remix I fix it giving approve to SC address from erc20 function, but I don't know how to do it when I run my test.
My SC:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "./Token.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";



library Random {
    /*
     * @dev startingValue is inclusive, endingValue is inclusive
     * naive implementation! Do not use in production
     * ie if 1, 10, rand int can include 1-10
     */
    function naiveRandInt(uint256 _startingValue, uint256 _endingValue)
        internal
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        // hash of the given block when blocknumber is one of the 256 most recent blocks; otherwise returns zero
        // create random value from block number; use previous block number just to make sure we aren't on 0
        uint randomInt = uint(blockhash(block.number - 1));
        // convert this into a number within range
        uint range = _endingValue - _startingValue + 1; // add 1 to ensure it is inclusive within endingValue

        randomInt = randomInt % range; // modulus ensures value is within range
        randomInt += _startingValue; // now shift by startingValue to ensure it is >= startingValue

        return randomInt;
    }
}

contract Lottery {
    IERC20 public erc20;
    uint256 public startTimestamp;
    uint256 public endTimestamp;
    uint256 public ticketCost;
    uint256 public ticketCounter;
    uint256 public winnerTicket;
    uint256 private prize;
    bool internal winnerWasChosen;
    address public _winner;

    mapping(address => uint256) s_players;
    mapping(uint256 => address) s_ticket;
    mapping(address => uint256) public _balances;


    constructor(uint256 _startTimestamp, uint256 _endTimestamp, uint256 _ticketCost, IERC20 _token) {
        startTimestamp = _startTimestamp;
        endTimestamp = _endTimestamp;
        ticketCost = _ticketCost;
        erc20 = IERC20(_token);
        
    }

    function buyTicket() public returns (uint256 ticketId)  {
        require(erc20.balanceOf(msg.sender) > ticketCost, "not enough balance");
        require(block.timestamp > startTimestamp, "Lottery is not started yet");
        require(endTimestamp > block.timestamp, "Lottery is over");
        require(s_players[msg.sender] == 0, "Already got one ticket");

        erc20.approve(address(this), 100);
        erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), ticketCost);
            ticketCounter++;
            s_players[msg.sender] = ticketCounter;
            s_ticket[ticketCounter] = msg.sender;
            return ticketCounter;
    }

    function chooseWinner() public returns (address winner ) {
        require(ticketCounter >= 1, "no tickets are sold");
        require(block.timestamp > endTimestamp, "Lottery isn't over");
        require(winnerWasChosen == false, "Function was already called");

        winnerTicket = Random.naiveRandInt(1, ticketCounter);
        _winner = s_ticket[winnerTicket];
        prize = ticketCost * ticketCounter;

        erc20.transfer(_winner, prize); 


        return (_winner);
        
    }

    function getStartLottery() public view returns (bool) {
        return (block.timestamp >= startTimestamp); 
    }

   function getEndLottery() public view returns (bool) {
       return (block.timestamp >= endTimestamp);  
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint) {
        return ticketCost;  
    }

    function getTimestamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return block.timestamp;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _addr) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[_addr];
    }
    
    function getPrize() public view returns (uint256){ 
        return ticketCost * ticketCounter;
    }

}
```

My unit test script with Truffle:

```
const { expect, assert } = require('chai');
const Lottery = artifacts.require('Lottery');
const Token = artifacts.require('Token');

contract('Lottery', (accounts) => {

    let test, startTimestamp, endTimestamp;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        token = await Token.deployed();
        lottery = await Lottery.deployed();
    

    it("records player when they buy ticket", async () => {
        await lottery.buyTicket()
        const contractPlayer = await lottery.getPlayer(0)
        assert.equal(user.address, contractPlayer)
    })

    it("SC is not empty", async () =>{
        await lottery.buyTicket()
        assert(lottery.address.valueOf() != 0)
    })

})
```

lottery.buyTicket() function returns me "insufficient allowance"

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion to switch to [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/): 90% of the problems that you run into with Truffle do not exist at all when testing smart contracts in Solidity directly, with Foundry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the allowance of `token` for the smart contract. As `token` is a separate smart contract, the `Lottery` is not allowed to manipulate with any tokens it doesn't own or is allowed to manipulate.

So the first example would be:

```
    it("records player when they buy ticket", async () => {
        const ticketCost = await lottery.ticketCost();
        await token.approve(lottery.address, ticketCost);

        await lottery.buyTicket();
        const contractPlayer = await lottery.getPlayer(0);
        assert.equal(user.address, contractPlayer);
    })
```

This way the smart contract is allowed to transfer the tokens.

Since `approve` sets the allowance for the address that you pass to transfer the funds of `msg.sender` calling it with `erc20.approve(address(this), 100);` within the smart contract would set the allowance for the smart contract for itself.

This happens because `msg.sender` value holds the address of the last entity in the transaction lifecycle. `tx.origin` is the one that is always equal to the originator of the smart contract, but its use is dangerous.